# How do you make Google desktop show all email text instead of a preview?

Tags: windows-xp, email, microsoft-outlook, google-desktop-search

When I search for emails in Google desktop, and click on a message in the results, I can only see the first 45 characters or so of the message. e.g. It shows the beginning of the message to about the 45th character and cuts the text off, even if the 45th character is in the middle of a word.

I thought this was normal behavior for Google desktop, and that it only shows a preview of the message. But I uninstalled Google desktop, re-installed, re-indexed everything, and I could see the entire contents of an email after clicking on subject in the search results. Then, after a couple months, Google Desktop is behaving the way it used to. It only shows the first 45 characters so of a message body, and I have to view the full message in Outlook.

Is there a setting I or something that I am missing? It is much more convenient to see the full text in google desktop itself, instead of clicking the 'view in outlook' link for each message in a conversation until I've found the specific email I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. Here's [a couple suggestions](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Desktop_Something-Broken/browse_thread/thread/ad790723a45e78ed/13fb31dc0944c15d).

I eventually stopped using it because it doesn't work with Outlook 2010.